# Почему начальное H в иностранных именах собственных часто транскрибируется как Г?

Tags: орфоэпия, заимствования

"Г" в таких словах, как Гамбург, Гаага, Генрих и даже Гарри, ещё можно объяснить тем, что, возможно, когда-то в прошлом было нормой произносить Г фрикативно (кстати, правда ли это?).  Но откуда оно в словах Гитлер и Гиммлер? (Кстати, когда и где впервые появилась транскрипция Hitler как Гитлер? Корпус русского языка не слишком помог.)  Сейчас в некоторых статьях имя Harry Harrison передают как Гарри Харрисон - это правильно или ошибка? (Harry произносится Хэрри в США и Харри в Великобритании.)

Откуда Г в слове Габима, и вообще почему ивритский артикль "ха" часто передают как "га" (например, Булгаков называет своего персонажа Га-Ноцри)?  Буква "хей" вовсе не читается как "г".

Как менялось произношение буквы "г" в прошлом? Если оно раньше было фрикативным, то когда стало твёрдым?  И как произносили эту букву в Киевской Руси?

Answer (score 5):

У вас очень много в самом вопросе всякой логики, на недостоверной информации построенной.

Давайте по-порядку. Прежде всего, для каждого языка свои нормы "переложения" (транскрипции и транслитерации) на русском. То, что вы смешиваете здесь не только германские, но и древние языки не свидетельствует о понимании ситуации.
А между тем, даже в английском и немецком языках h произносится по-разному.

Дальше. В русском нет точного соответствия этому звуку ни в одном языке, слова из которых вы привели. Как ни передай - всё равно будет "неправильно". Г ничуть не хуже любого другого варианта.

И последнее на эту тему. В большинстве случаев вариант определяется традицией. Бесполезно спрашивать, почему Гарри, но Харрисон, если именно такое написание закрепилось.

Остаётся рассмотреть только историю, откуда вообще эта традиция взялась.
Как уже говорил, для разных языков традиция может быть разной. Проще всего разобраться с заимствованиями из немецкого. Совершенно очевидно, что по крайней мере в этом случае традиция касается не только личных имён. Возьмите "бухгалтер", "галстук" или "гауптвахта" да и само слово "Германия", "германский" восходит к немецкому herr. Нет никаких причин для современных имен (включая Гитлера с камарильей) делать какое-то исключение.

Почему именно так? Давайте разберемся. Точного соответствия этому звуку в русском нет. Было бы большой ошибкой считать его эквивалентным русскому Х. Фактически в немецком это простой выдох через чуть напряженные голосовые связки (в английской - он и вовсе совершенно свободный), ларингал (гортанно-горловой), который по положению основных звуковых органов можно отнести как к фрикативным, так и к аппроксимантам. (См. [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82))

У этого звука нет звонкого соответствия ни в одном европейском, а все близкие по качеству глухие обычно "заняты". Ближе всего к нему стоит современное украинское (и южнорусское) Г, которое представляет собой тот же ларингал (только звонкий и более напряженный, "хрипящий"), он обозначается в МФА через [ɦ], не удивительно, что этот и похожие звуки в других языках на украинском последовательно передаются через Г.

Считается, что вплоть до XVIII века (а в северных диалектах - и того дольше) в русском языке Г тоже произносилось не взрывным, а фрикативным, близким к современному в словах "ага", "господи", "благо" и некоторых других в их классическом произношении. Этот звук, обозначаемый в МФА как [ɣ], сохранился также в белорусском как основной аллофон фонемы Г.

Звук этот представляет собой выраженный велярный фрикатив, на русский слух он почти не отличим от украинского варианта (хотя по таблице МФА отстоит от него довольно далеко, люди владеющие обоими языками, украинским и белорусским, хорошо их различают). Этот же звук считается правильной исторической передачей церковнославянского "Глаголя". 
Таким образом, хотя этот звук в русском и не совсем соответствует украинскому, все же является довольно близким к исходному немецкому h. 
Выбор вполне обоснован.

В письменной же традиции фиксируется не позднее петровской эпохи, когда влияние голландского (который смешивали с немецким) было трудно переоценить. Голландское же G очень специфично, оно вообще ни на что не похоже, меньше всего на G немецкое (и современное русское), поэтому буква Г была как бы "свободна" для кодирования европейского h. Окончательно было закреплено уже во времена Ломоносова, когда уже собственно немцы заправляли при дворе и в академии, хотя уже тогда было понятно, что русское Г уже довольно далеко ушло от идеала для такой замены.

С семитскими и другими языками - это отдельная история, но в целом суть та же. Выбирали, исходя из того, что поближе тогдашнему русскому слуху, а не того, что мы сейчас об этом думаем. А потом, в последующие эпохи, уже определяла традиция.

Comment: Не знаю, где вы углядели "логику, на недостоверной информации построенную". Если то, что вы пишете, правда, то моя догадка, что Г раньше было фрикативным, верна.

Comment: @user31264 догадка верна, но вы же не ограничились это догадкой вы задали десяток вопросов, в которых прослеживается явная логика, что это во всех языках один звук, что его надо передавать одной и той же буквой в русском, что зависит от страны, а не от языка (английский британский - американский) и прочее. Т.е. вы не нейтральный вопрос задали, а продаливали некую мысль. Что в принципе не возбраняется, но тут вы ошиблись

Comment: Задал, потому что связаны с главным вопросом и с догадкой.

Comment: Я отредактировал комментарий, он у меня "сорвался" раньше времени..

Comment: не понятен предпоследний абзац

Comment: Там Х звучит, хоть и не чёткое: https://ru.forvo.com/word/adolf_hitler/

Comment: @oleedd Где "там"? В слове Hitler? Я знаю. )))) Только не Х, а немецкое H (h). Простой, немного напряженный выдох. Оно сильно отличается от "Ха" в слове ich. ==== Вообще доверяйте больше транскрипции (МФА), а не своим слуховым ощущениям.

Comment: Просто оно ни грамма не похоже на русскую или украинскую Г. Х ближе всего по звучанию.

Comment: @oleedd - ваши проблемы, если вы так слышите.