# Почему переводится по-разному?

Tags: заимствования, переводы, транслитерация

Почему, например, слова с одинаковым началом - Himmelstadt, Hillersleben и Hitler - при переводе пишутся и произносятся по-разному? Слова Himmelstadt и Hillersleben пишутся и звучат как Химмельштадт и Хиллерслебен (стоящее впереди буквосочетание Hi пишется и звучит как Хи), а в слове Hitler Hi пишется и звучит как Ги - Гитлер? С чего бы это?

Comment: Похожий пример: *Henry — Генрих*.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему начальное H в иностранных именах собственных часто транскрибируется как Г?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431362/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-h-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%93)

Comment: @oleedd: не совсем, Henry английское, а Генрих немецкое. А вот если, например, взять О. Генри без Х, тогда конечно. Или немецкое Heinrich.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Брал из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Генрих_VIII). Почему-то появилось Х в имени английского короля.

Comment: @oleedd: а-а, точно, короли действительно Генрихами зовутся у нас!

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.forvo.com/word/adolf_hitler/) как немцы произносят. Кто согласен с behemothus'ом, что там похоже не на Х, а на украинскую Г?

Comment: А также Карлами, Яковами, Людовиками и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Это с традиции, — за ней вообще насчитывается много косяков. Например, немецкое же личное имя Heinrich читается вовсе не «Генрих», а «Хайнрих». И Австрия на самом деле Österreich, т. е. «Остерайх» — именно не «рейх», а «р**а**йх»! И много чего ещё. Менять всё это уже поздно: к неправильным формам привыкли. Можно только насаждать по возможности соответствующее оригинальному произношению написание тех имён и названий, у которых ещё нет традиции написания. Что в общем-то и делается.

Answer (score 0):

Просто сложилось так, что для перевода H выбирают (или выбирали) Х либо Г. И речь в том числе и о английском, например:
https://wooordhunt.ru/word/henry
Наверно, просто при переводе смотрели, какая буква будет лучше звучать во всём слове. Иначе бы существовал только один вариант — прямой (H — Х, G — Г).

Буква Г добавляет слову грозности, "Хитлер" на русском не звучит уверенно, жёстко, строго, не передаёт сущность жестокого диктатора.